# Reqular Expression to match characters between to values

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match a certain string which would be a name

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]{1, 10}/", "stackoverflow");
```

but this gives me an error how would I match if the string is greater than value a  and less than value b?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the string being a greater or lesser value, but the syntax error is probably due to the space in the `{1, 10}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Too much whitespace.

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{1,10}/
```

Comment: Aha I see reqular expressions are white space sensitive, will that expression match values between 1 and 10?

Comment: @Aaron, unless you specifically disable white-space sensitivity.

Comment: @Aaron, no it won't... it will match between 1 and 10 alpha characters at the start of the string, it has nothing to do values as such

Answer (score 1):

***Two issues:***

1. No whitespace allowed within `{x,y}`
2. You should use `preg_replace` not `preg_match`

***Your code should be:***

```
$input = "Frank";
$output = preg_replace("/^[a-zA-Z]{1,10}/", "stackoverflow", $input);   
print $output;
```